# metasploit: run nmap on compromised host

Tags: nmap, metasploit

I have just compromised a computer(legal in my local environment) and want to run nmap from that host to see further inside the network. I know I can use metasploit modules like "auxillary/scanner/portscan/tcp/", but it seems like it isnt as good as nmap. I tested this by running nmap on a an ip from my computer and the module from the compromised host(route add). But the module only gets ssh up, while nmap gets several like port 80, 443 and more.

It might be that the compromised computer is blocked my firewall, but I think that is highly unlikely.

So how do I run nmap from the compromised host?

Both my computer and the compromised one are on the same IP range, but I wanted to see if the module is as good as nmap.

If i run nmap from msfconsole after adding a route, will nmap then do the scanning from the compromised host?

Comment: why not upload nmap and run it on the target?

Comment: I dont know how. Do you have any link that can help me achieve that?

Comment: This is all stuff that's covered in the basic metasploit books and official pages. If you have a meterpreter session, you can use `upload`

Comment: Thanks! Is uploading nmap to scan again the way the professionals do it? Or will they be satisfied with using metasploits modules.

Comment: They use the method that works. Sometimes you can successfully tunnel traffic through the target, sometimes you can't. Sometimes built-in modules work, sometimes they don't.

Comment: drop a ssh executable on victim and tunnel all traffic.